# i want ho highlight the tableView rows and make space between them in swift

Tags: ios, swift

[here's an image of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZtUn.png)

[and here's what I actually have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVQJl.png)

here's my code is

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView == sideMenu {
        tableView.rowHeight = 60
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! SideMenuTableViewCell
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 0.486, green: 0.733, blue: 0.384, alpha: 1)
        cell.name.text = arr[indexPath.row]["name"] as? String
        cell.logo.setImage(arr[indexPath.row]["icon"] as? UIImage, for: .normal)
        return cell
    }
```

please tell me how to make space between rows and highlight them

Comment: You need to take all item in UIView and give Top & Bottom Space to ContainerView Of TableViewCell and remove separator as none.

Comment: Or use collectionview composition(recommend) layout or flowlayout

Answer (score 0):

Take the light area with name and logo as a standalone `UIView` and add top-bottom margin for the `cell.contentView` as *custom separator*.

```swift
containerView = UIView()
name = UIView()
logo = UIImageView()

containerView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
contentView.backgroundColor = .gray

contentView.addSubview(containerView)
containerView?.addSubview(name)
containerView?.addSubview(logo)

containerView?.snp.makeConstraints({ (make) in
    make.width.centerX.centerY.equalTo(contentView)
    make.height.equalTo(contentView).offset(-20)  // custom separator line height.
})
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand, do you mean the light area for the tableview cell?